# regexp variable include [ at tcl

Tags: regex, variables, tcl

I have a list

```
a1 = a[3] b[4] c[5]

a2 = a[3]
```

but

```
regexp $a2 $a1
```

does not work

how could i `regexp` it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[`bracket`]` characters are special to ***both*** Tcl in general ***and*** the `regexp` command in particular. You need to take special care when using them.

However, if you are just using `regexp` to look for a literal string in another string, you can do a trick:

```
regexp ***=$a2 $a1
```

The `***=` says “the rest of this regular expression is really just a literal string”.

But you can also use `string first` (or `string last`) to do this sort of search:

```
string first $a2 $a1
# It's result is the index of the first character where the searched-for string is
# or -1 if the string isn't there
```

Comment: i use ***= can successfully regexp the variable that include "[", thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have a list where the items contain bracket characters. Such a list is awkward to write in Tcl code, since brackets have a syntactic function (the interpreter performs command substitution on the text within them). To be able to write it, the brackets must be *escaped* using either braces around the whole list, or by putting backslashes before each bracket character (actually only the opening bracket needs to be backslashed, but we'll ignore that for now.) So, both:

```
% set a1 {a[3] b[4] c[5]}
```

and

```
% set a1 "a\[3\] b\[4\] c\[5\]"
```

produce a string that can be used as a list, looking like this:

```
a[3] b[4] c[5]
```

Now, how to tell if the item `a[3]` is in the list? We could use `regexp` to try to match it. Again, we must escape the braces:

```
% regexp {a[3]} $a1  ;  # WRONG!
```

This doesn't work, because the pattern language that the regular expression engine uses **also** treats brackets as a special character (in this case, it tries to match a string consisting of an "a" and then a character from a set that only consists of "3"). So, the brackets must be doubly escaped:

```
% regexp {a\[3\]} $a1
```

Now we get a correct result of 1.

This would also work, but this is far too many backslashes to be comfortable.

```
% regexp "a\\\[3\\\]" $a1
```

As a rule of thumb, always brace the pattern argument to `regexp` and add further backslashes inside as needed.

Regexp matching isn't the only way to find an item in a list, however. You can also do *text matching*, a.k.a. *glob matching* (though this doesn't really improve anything in this example):

```
% string match {*a\[3\]*} $a1
```

You can also do *exact matching*; this kind of match does not in itself have any special characters (still have to escape against the interpreter):

```
% string first {a[3]} $a1
```

(a result >=0 means found, <0 means not found)

Since you are working on a list, you could do any of these searches with the list searching command `lsearch`:

```
% lsearch -regexp $a1 {a\[3\]}
% lsearch -glob $a1 {a\[3\]}
% lsearch -exact $a1 {a[3]}
```

In each of these cases, you get either the index number of the first item to match, or -1 if no item matches.

Documentation:
[lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm),
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Comment: why can't i success?                                                                               % set a1 "b\\[5\\] a\\[3\\] c\\[6\\]"
b[5] a[3] c[6]
% set tmp [split $a1]
{b[5]} {a[3]} {c[6]}
% set a2 "a\\[3\\]"
a[3]
% regexp $a2 $a1
0

Comment: the lsearch command is work for get the variable include "[" , thanks for your detailed discription!!

Answer (score 1):

the regexp ***=$a2 $a1 trick worked for my case as well. Mine has "(" and ")" in variable, and the variable comes from outside so I cannot control the content, so this ***= method is the amazing solution. My example below

```
(pv_tcl) 201 % set results RX_SPARE(0)
(pv_tcl) 203 % set bit_name RX_SPARE(10)
(pv_tcl) 212 % set r2 RX_SPARE(10)
(pv_tcl) 214 % regexp ***=$bit_name $r2 ;#this matches
1
(pv_tcl) 216 % regexp ***=$bit_name $results ;#this does not match
0
```